# Windows 7 - Error: connect ENOENT //./pipe/docker_engine

Tags: docker, windows-7

I have installed DockerToolbox-1.12.2.exe in Windows 7 from https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/tag/v1.12.2 link. After installation, if I try to launch Kitamatic, I am getting 
[![enter image description here][1]]
Error: connect ENOENT //./pipe/docker_engine.

I have tried RETRY SETUP and USE VIRTUALBOX options available, but didn't helped much. Can anyone suggest, how to proceed?

Comment: I have the same problem on window 10 home.

Comment: The answer i get today https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/548